# How can I restore the Bash prompt?

Tags: profile

For work I just did `source .profile` from other user, but it changed my bash prompt.

It used to be

```
[leche@xxx home]$
[leche@xxx home]$
```

And now it appears like:

```
[leche@xxx] [10:18 AM$] /home $
 $
 [leche@xxx] [10:18 AM$] /home $
 $
```

How may I change it back?

Comment: `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.profile` or `source /etc/profile`.

Comment: The change is only temporary. You could simply close the shell and open a new shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

Search the manual for PS1.